# In a Swift macOS Application that displays progress indicators in a custom Cell, is it possible to synchronise the spinning of all the indicators?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a Cocoa Application written in Swift / Objective-C and I have a problem that is just a detail, but I deem it important. I have a view-based `NSOutlineView` driven with a datasource and a delegate, and I have created a custom `NSTableViewCell` that only contains a spinning progress indicator. The problem is, When the app window opens, only the visible spinning indicators spin in sync. If I enlarge the window and more `NSOutlineView` cells get displayed the new appearing spinning indicators do not spin in sync. This is logically correct, since I instantiate the cell in the `NSOutlineView` delegate method:

```
outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView?
```

My code is as follows:

```
let view = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier:NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier.init("activityProgressTableViewCell"), owner: self) as! ProgressIndicatorTableCellView

view.unFinishedStatusIndicator.startAnimation(self)
```

So I believe it is normal that the indicators are not in sync since they start spinning on different moments. Can anybody suggest a pattern to address this issue ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I am aware that I could use Cocoa Bindings instead of calling startAnimation on the indicator, and this could allow me to start the animation of all indicators at once, but How to handle spinning indicators in sub-items in the NSOutlineView ?

Comment: You could write your own custom activity indicators that take their timing from some master clock.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a possible solution, by using indeed Cocoa Bindings. In my main controller class, I have declared a property like this:

```
@objc dynamic var shouldStartFoldersIndicators: Bool = true
```

Then, in interface builder, I bind the animate binding of the progress indicator in the cell to that path of the main controller. Then, In this delegate method:

```
outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView?
```

When I need to display the spinning indicator cell, I set the Bool property to false, then to true. Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
self.shouldStartFoldersIndicators = false
self.shouldStartFoldersIndicators = true
```

In order to make it work, I had to defer the statements to the next running loop like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.shouldStartFoldersIndicators = false
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.shouldStartFoldersIndicators = true
   }
}
```

This works well, although I am afraid it could slow down the NSOutlineView redrawing. I thank you in advance for any better solution. Thanks